# Session variables causing object reference not set

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET 4.5 web application with 2 pages: Index.aspx and Preview.aspx
On the index page I store a List called inputList in a Session variable.
Also I store in a different Session variable a string called fileName from an excel file that I'm uploading. I use Server.Transfer to reach Preview.aspx

There I have 2 private variables that I initialize with those 2 Session variables.

The problem is that if I wait for more than 1 minute while being on the Index page before I hit the button to do Server.Transfer, when I reach the Preview page I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Is this happening because the Session variable is timed out ?
This is what my web.config has:

The idle timeout on the application pool is 20 minutes. 
I don't understand why I'm getting this error.

Could it be that Server.Transfer is causing my local variables to be null ?

Is this something browser based ? I noticed that in IE & FF this happens after idle-ing for about 1 min, but on Chrome this happens after 10 mins.

Code:

```
//Index.aspx
private string fileName;
private List<string> inputList = new List<string>();

//when the user clicks on the upload button
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   inputList.Clear();
   fileName = UserId.Text + "_" + FileUploadToServer.PostedFile.FileName;
   Session["fileName"] = fileName;
   for (int i = 0; i < clientInputRange.Count(); i++)
   {
     string clientValue = clientInputRange.ElementAt(i).Text;
     inputList.Add(clientValue);
   }
   Session["inputList"] = inputList;
}

protected void PreviewBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Server.Transfer("~/Preview.aspx");
}

//Preview.aspx
private string fileName = "";
private List<string> inputList = new List<string>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!IsPostBack)
   {
       inputList = Session["inputList"] as List<string>;
       fileName = Session["fileName"] as string;

       //Here is where I'm getting the error
       for (int i = 0; i < inputList.Count; i++)
       {
           ....
       }
   }
}
```

*Update: The session id is the same on both pages. But the session variables are null.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: Well on the Index page I have: Session["fileName"] = "SomeUserName";   and Session["inputList"] = inputList; //where inputList is a List<string> that I add some values to it before assigning it to Session["inputList"]. When the user presses a button, I do Server.Transfer("~/Preview.aspx");   When it reaches preview.aspx I have in PageLoad:  if(!IsPostBack){fileName = Session["fileName"] as string;  and inputList = Session["inputList] as List<string>; It works fine on localhost, but when I put it on the server( IIS 7.5), it gives me that error after waiting for a minute between pages.

Comment: Please edit the question instead of posting code down here in the comments

Comment: Although not helpful to solve the question, i want to add here that if you use session variables like this to store large objects, you will face scalability and performance issues.

Comment: If that inputList contains 100 string values of about 3-20 characters each, would it affect performance that much ? I know it's wrong to do this for lists of hundreds of thousands of items like other people have..but could this be the problem here ?